What does $(\frac{2}{3}+C_{n-1})$ mean in the representation of the $n$-th member of Cantor set
In this Wikipedia's page on Cantor set, the recursive formula for the nth member is as follows:
$
C_{n} := \frac{C_{n-1}}{3} \cup (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{C_{n-1}}{3}).
$
But I don't quite understand what $+$ does in this formula, if it represents the translation operator applied on the interval then the resulting set doesn't match the actual member of the set.
By simple translation I mean if a set $A = (1, 2)$ then $A + 1 = (2, 3)$.

The first + should be 'union', I think

@Empy2, that's right, thanks for pointing that out!

It is simple translation, but you've misquoted the formula from Wikipedia, which might be the cause of your confusion.

@MishaLavrov, I've updated the quoted formula, still I can see that translating $C_{n-1}$ ($\forall n \gt 2$) by $\frac{2}{3}$ of 1 unit would result in an interval that contains some elements outside of the closed interval $[0, 1]$?

right, but you're translating $C_{n-1}/3$ not $C_{n-1}$

@MatthewTowers, oh right, my bad! Thanks for pointing that out.

Based on the result, it should be $A+x\triangleq{x+y:y\in A}$.

@MostafaAyaz, it is, thank you for explicitly writing it out!
